# using a function in another function - javascript

Tags: javascript, function

im learning js and i have a problem that i couldn't solve.
i need to use a randomizer function in order to generate two random numbers, and insert those numbers into the second function to print out the outcome. im pretty lost to how to do it, appreciate the help.

```js
function getRandomInt() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}


function moduloEx7(number, comparer) {
  if (number > comparer && number % comparer !== 0) {
    let module = number % comparer;
    myMessage += `The number ${number} is bigger than ${comparer}. But the modulo of ${number} % ${comparer} is ${module}`;
  } else if (number > comparer) {
    myMessage += `The number ${number} is bigger than ${comparer}`;
  } else if (number < comparer) {
    myMessage += `The number ${number} is less than ${comparer}`;
  } else if (number === comparer) {
    myMessage += `The number ${number} is equal to ${comparer}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: do you mean like: `moduloEx7(getRandomInt(), getRandomInt());`? Just don't forget to return something (`myMessage`) from the function and assign it our log it.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply.  i think what i need is to put the randomizer in the second function, then when i call the first function it calls the randomizer to create two random numbers.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading this. statement: "_insert those numbers into the second function_" - As the function is written, it requires two parameters (presumably random numbers). If you _create_ the random numbers _inside_ the function, they would not be _inserted_ into the function but _created within_ the function. What do you think? Also, the question refers to "two functions" - I believe the intent is for you to pass the random numbers into the second function.

Comment: hey, this would be the wording:
Add a new function that randomize the values of your two variables, using Math.random(), with the range of 1 - 100. Call to that function inside the other one instead of providing two parameters.

Comment: Ok...that is much clearer - and you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function moduloEx7 and inside calls getRandomInt() function and assigns his returned value to number and comparer variables, remember to return myMessage variable:

```js
function getRandomInt() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}


function moduloEx7() {

  let number = getRandomInt();
  let comparer = getRandomInt();
  let module = number % comparer;
  let myMessage = '';

  if (number > comparer && number % comparer !== 0) {  
    myMessage += `The number ${number} is bigger than ${comparer}. But the modulo of ${number} % ${comparer} is ${module}`;
  } else if (number > comparer) {
    myMessage += `The number ${number} is bigger than ${comparer}`;
  } else if (number < comparer) {
    myMessage += `The number ${number} is less than ${comparer}`;
  } else if (number === comparer) {
    myMessage += `The number ${number} is equal to ${comparer}`;
  }
  return myMessage;
}

console.log(moduloEx7())
```

Comment: hey, thanks, I dont want to put getRandomInt as arguments, i would like them to be part of function moduloEx7, so when i call moduloEx7 it automatically calls on getRandomInt as a parameter or such. is this possible?

Comment: you can declare variables inside the function body and assign the returned value of getRandomInt() function. let number = getRandomInt(); let comparer = getRandomInt();

Comment: thanks, that seems to work, but could getRandomInt  also be the parameters of the function?

Comment: yes of course, it's possible. Exactly what you are looking for?